# 403 error trying to access admin panel on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, authentication, http-status-code-403

I'm having trouble accessing my Tomcat admin panel. I've configured everything correctly as far as I can see (adding an admin/manager user to tomcat-users.xml). I can log into manager/html and enter my credentials, then get presented with a 403 error. I've got the tomcat7-admin package installed on my system and tomcat is installed to the default location. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

`tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user name="admin" password="adminpass" roles="manager,admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

If it helps, I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 x64.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the logs?

Answer (score 2):

I think the field is "username" not name. So it should look like the entry below:

`<user username="admin" password="adminpass" roles="manager,admin" />`